# React Native Error: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection - Cannot read property data

Tags: javascript, react-native, lodash

I'm having a strange problem that I can't quite pinpoint with my React Native app. I'm using Lodash to cycle through a API response to set the state of an array of locations using the returned response after clearing the array. When I display just the value / key of the response within the loop, it works fine, but when I try using setState, I get a possible unhanded promise error.

Here's the code for the loop and setting state:

```js
    updateMarkers(payload) {
        this.setState({
            markers: []
        })
        let id = 0
        _.forOwn(payload, function(value, key) {
            this.setState({
                markers: [
                    ...this.state.markers,
                    {
                        coordinate: key.coordinates,
                        key: id++
                    }
                ]
            })
        })
        console.log(this.state.markers)
    }
```

Here's the response I'm receiving:

```html
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:113197:55
    at tryCallOne (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:25822:8)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:25908:9
    at JSTimersExecution.callbacks.(anonymous function) (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:8801:13)
    at Object.callTimer (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:8581:1)
    at Object.callImmediatesPass (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:8680:19)
    at Object.callImmediates (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:8695:25)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:7405:43
    at guard (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:7283:1)
    at MessageQueue.__callImmediates (http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:7405:1)
```

This is what the returned object looks like when I console log the value and key (without setting state). It cycles through each object correctly.

```html
Object {coordinates: Object, description: "Machine F", distance: 1.220632249131323, inventory: Array[16], pid: "-KP6ulcT9qeDb1oFFrVA"}
coordinates:Object
description:"Machine F"
distance:1.220632249131323
inventory:Array[16]
pid:"-KP6ulcT9qeDb1oFFrVA"
__proto__:Object
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you bind `this` to the function `updateMarkers` when calling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `this` reference in '_.forOwn' second parameter doesn't point your react class. Javascript function don't keep the `this` of surrounding context. You should use ES6 arrow function to keep this context. Also Your call `this.setState({markers: []})` can cause problem as well.

```
_.forOwn(payload,(value, key) => {
            this.setState({
                markers: [
                    ...this.state.markers,
                    {
                        coordinate: key.coordinates,
                        key: id++
                    }
                ]
            })
        })
```

Also this.setState calls are not synchronous, so in your _.forOwn callback, there is no gurantee that this.state.markers will be available. You should refactor your code so only once setState call is made with new markers array after your _.forOwn call.

```
var markers =[]
        let id = 0
        _.forOwn(payload, function(value, key) {
            markers.push({
                        coordinate: key.coordinates,
                        key: id++
                    });
        });
this.setState({markers},()=>{console.log(this.state.markers)});
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and answer. This worked and I think I understand the concept a bit better now.